# wxPython wx.ListCtrl with specific data

Tags: wxpython, listitem, listctrl

I want to add to wx.ListCtrl from wxPython items that have a specific ID associated to them. How can I achieve that? Actually, how do you associate any data to a specific ListCtrl item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a dictionary where the keys are the IDs and then use the ListCtrl's SetItemData to associate the key the list control item. Then you can use the GetItemData method to retrieve the ID and use that with your dictionary to get the data.

Or you could use the `ListCtrlPyDataMixin` which would make this a bit easier:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls#Python_Data_Mixin

Personally, I really like using ObjectListView instead of the straight wx.ListCtrl. Here's a tutorial on how it works:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

And as @nepix32 mentioned, you could also use the wx.DataViewCtrl, if you have wxPython 2.9 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can associate a `long` with `wx.ListCtrl` [.SetItemData](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html#ListCtrl.SetItemData) and [.GetItemData](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html#ListCtrl.GetItemData) methods (e. g. for a `row_id` from a database.

However, if you have a fairly recent wxPython (>= 2.9), you should be better of with the `wx.DataViewCtrl`. It is more powerful and easier to program than the ListCtrl and it brings a `PyDataViwModel` with it, which allows you to map objects to the view items.

Nearer to the ListCtrl is the `wx.DataViewListCtrl` which is quite similar to the `wx.ListCtrl` in function scope.